# Blender Exported GLTF rendered some materials partly black in scene

Tags: three.js, blender, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei, mixamo

**Lighting:** (The 2nd picture is using ambient light at 0.8 intesity. )

I tried ambient, Directional and Evironment lights, but no result.

Here is the Armature with all the materials in blender:

[image]

Here is how the model renders using GLTFjsx or GLTFLoader:

[image]

Comment: Please include (1) the material configuration in Blender, and (2) your code in three.js, not just screenshots of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DonMcCurdy.

**Solution**

I had to convert my charcter's material type from spec/gloss to metal/rough.

*Convert from spec/gloss to metal/rough before editing in Blender, requires Node.js:*

```
npm install --global @gltf-transform/cli
gltf-transform metalRough yourModel.glb yourModel.glb
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see much of the material's configuration in Blender, but it doesn't appear to be a Principled BSDF node as required for export. Most of Blender's materials — and certainly any complex node graph — cannot be exported to any format. For whichever format you're exporting to, you'll need to consult the docs, and in the case of glTF those options are covered at:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html

I would also strongly recommend testing the model first in a viewer like https://gltf.report/. Display bugs can very easily be related to your code or lighting.

Comment: Using the https://gltf.report/ is pretty useful! (would be nice if it worked like sandboxes). https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/267114/171820 Your answer here helped me so much understand. Thank you